# Haskell: Why does my implementation of last work for an empty list?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through exercises in Graham Hutton's book "Programming in Haskell" and as part of one exercise I've re-implemented Haskell's `last` function like so:

```
lasst xs = drop (length xs - 1) xs
```

Now this works nicely for a non-empty list:

```
> lasst [1,2,3,4,5]
[5]
```

But, surprisingly to me, for an empty list it returns an empty list:

```
> lasst []
[]
```

I'm surprised by this because I would expect `(length []) - 1` to be evaluated into `-1` and the subsequent evaluation of `drop -1 []` to throw.

Why does my implementation return an empty list for an empty list, rather than throw an exception?

Comment: You should use brackets for `-1`, so `drop (-1) []`, since otherwise you perform a `drop - 1 []`, which does not make much sense.

Comment: If the index is negative, then it drops no elements. This is covered in the Haskell report as well.

Comment: Thanks @willem-van-onsem. Indeed the exception I saw coming from `drop -1 []` was due to the missing parentheses. When I add them, `drop (-1) []` returns `[]` as per spec.

Comment: That's not an exception.

Comment: BTW `drop (length xs - 1) xs` is horribly inefficient: it will walk the list once to get its length; then again to drop the prefix. Better is to code `lasst` directly using pattern matching. (You could then code it to throw an exception on an empty list.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Haskell report '10](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010) specifies the the [*standard Prelude*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1). In this section, we see:

> ```
> drop                   :: Int -> [a] -> [a]  
> drop n xs     | n <= 0 =  xs  
> drop _ []              =  []  
> drop n (_:xs)          =  drop (n-1) xs
> ```

So for a negative `n`, it will return the entire list. This makes sense with respect to the [documentation of **`drop`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop):

> `drop n xs` returns the suffix of `xs` after the **first `n` elements**, or `[]` if `n > length xs`.

So the first `-1` elements of a list, are no elements at all.

This is further covered in one of the examples of `drop`:

> ```
> drop (-1) [1,2] == [1,2]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`drop` and `take` are total functions: they always return something without causing a runtime error, no matter what the (total) arguments are. Their definition makes it so that

```
take k xs ++ drop k xs == xs
```

holds for every `k` and (finite) `xs`. Note that `k` can be negative, or even larger than the length of `xs`, and the above is still guaranteed.

It might be surprising at first, but they have the following behavior. Assume `xs = [1,2,3]`. Then

```
 k      take     drop
==========================
 ...
 -2     []       [1,2,3]
 -1     []       [1,2,3]
 0      []       [1,2,3]
 1      [1]      [2,3]
 2      [1,2]    [3]
 3      [1,2,3]  []
 4      [1,2,3]  []
 5      [1,2,3]  []
 ...
```

Personally, I'm unsure about whether their totality is a good idea. It would make sense for them to cause a runtime error for negative `k`, or for `k` larger than the length. Still, that's what Haskell does.

(Note in passing that `tail xs` and `drop 1 xs` differ when `xs=[]`, because `tail` is not total.)

Comment: Why did you qualify this with "finite"? Doesn't that hold for infinite lists too?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes, if `==` is denotational equivalence. If that's Haskell equality, instead, we do not have `[0..] == [0..]` evaluate to `True`. (Initially, I did leave it out, then I became more pedantic and added it just to be safe.)

Comment: Yes, but if you mean Haskell equality, then you need a bunch of other exceptions too, like `undefined` in one of the lists, or types with pathological `Eq` instances like `Double`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Above I require total arguments, so `undefined` is out. One should also indeed assume a reflexive `Eq` (`Eq Double` is not because of NaN, I assume). Enumerating all the exact assumptions is troublesome :-/